# firebase verification link - with localhost

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I want to pass my own verification link to the users email (and not that default one from `firebaseapp.com`) To edit the link I went to the tamplates and passed a route from my project. [image]

Now when I click on the email link - the `emailVerified` value is still `false`. I subscribe to a mapped `Observable<User>` to see the current state of the user.
Its mapped in my OAuthService `constructor` like this

```
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('is verified:', user.emailVerified);
        return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
  })
```

How do I send the `emailVerification` method? Its as follows:

```
  public register(register: RegisterDataModel): void {
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(register.email, register.password)
      .then(() => {
        const user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
        user.updateProfile({displayName: register.username, photoURL: null}).then(() => {
          this.setUserDoc(user).then(() => {
            user.sendEmailVerification().then(() => console.log('please verify your email'))
              .catch((err) => console.log(err));
          });
        });
      }).catch(
      (err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Even on the email the link is not propperly formatted. The link is arriving like this:
[image]

As you may see, firebase is sending the localhost link 2 times concatinated.

Comment: Are you following these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler Also when you provide your custom callback URL, make sure you are copying your link correctly. It looks like you are providing an incorrect one in the Firebase Console.

Comment: apperently no... I didnt.^^ Thanks for the link.